# How to add content in sharepoint file using C# api

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I want to add content to existing file in sharepoint .
I am using below code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using MSharp.Framework.Services;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;

namespace SharepointFileSend
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string V = "XXXXX";
        private static string hostWeb="XXXXX.sharepoint.com";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string siteUrl = "https://XXXXX.sharepoint.com/site/";

            string password = "XXX";
            //Insert Credentials
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

            var securePassword = new SecureString();

            foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray() ) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("XXXX@XXXXX.com", securePassword);
            Web site = context.Web;

            //Get the required RootFolder
            string barRootFolderRelativeUrl = "Documents/Demo";
            Folder barFolder = site.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(barRootFolderRelativeUrl);

            //Create new subFolder to load files into
            string newFolderName = "SPTest";
            barFolder.Folders.Add(newFolderName);
            barFolder.Update();

            //Add file to new Folder
            Folder currentRunFolder = site.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(barRootFolderRelativeUrl + "/" + newFolderName);
            string sharePointDocPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString(), "Sharepoint.xml");

            FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation { Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(sharePointDocPath), Url = Path.GetFileName(sharePointDocPath), Overwrite = true };
            currentRunFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
            currentRunFolder.Update();

            context.ExecuteQuery();

            //Return the URL of the new uploaded file
           // string newUrl = siteUrl + barRootFolderRelativeUrl + "/" + newFolderName + "/" + Path.GetFileName(@p);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting exception at last statement :

context.ExecuteQuery();

System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.'

Please help in resolving this exception and also adding content to  the existing sharepoint file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the default "Documents" library, the root folder relative Url of the library in your code is "**Shared%20Documents/Demo**". And check if the site url is right.

The following example code for your reference.

```
string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/team";
string userName = "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
string password = "xxxx";


var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password)
{
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}

var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
ctx.Credentials = credentials;
Web site = ctx.Web;

//Get the required RootFolder
string barRootFolderRelativeUrl = "Shared%20Documents/Demo";
Folder barFolder = site.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(barRootFolderRelativeUrl);

//Create new subFolder to load files into
string newFolderName = "SPTest";
barFolder.Folders.Add(newFolderName);
barFolder.Update();

//Add file to new Folder
Folder currentRunFolder = site.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(barRootFolderRelativeUrl + "/" + newFolderName);
string sharePointDocPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString(), "Sharepoint.xml");

FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation { Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(sharePointDocPath), Url = Path.GetFileName(sharePointDocPath), Overwrite = true };
currentRunFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
currentRunFolder.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: I got 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.'

Comment: Please make sure the "https://XXXXX.sharepoint.com/site" is a site url.

Comment: I have a little confusion here . xxxx.sharepoint.com/site   redirect me to "you don't have access." page but xxxx.sharepoint.com takes me to home page of sharepoint . So, https://xxxx.sharepoint.com is a site url?

Comment: When i use XXXXX.sharepoint.com/site  i get : 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.' and when i use XXXXX.sharepoint.com/ as site url then i get 400 Bad Request.